# Chaining Methods error in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, chaining

I would like to know the reason why this simple piece of code fails:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr.push(arr[0]).shift();
console.log(arr);
```

it returns in firebug console "TypeError: arr.push(...).shift is not a function"

I think it happens because I invoke the shift() method not on an array but on the pushed element.

Is there a more elegant way to obtain the same result that,

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr.push(arr[0]);
arr.shift();
console.log(arr);
```

produce ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The close vote here is very strange... Please read the question til the end before voting.

Comment: If I made something wrong, I ask sorry. As you can see from my rep I'm not what you can call a veteran and maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially this question is saying, can I somehow "elegantly" express the notion of moving the first item of an array to the end. Luckily, JS is a Turing-complete language, which allows us to define functions, so the "elegant" answer is just

```
rotate(arr)
```

Now it merely remains to define `rotate`. To rotate is to **drop** the first element in the result of **adding** the **head** element to the end:

```
function rotate(arr) { return drop(add(arr, head(arr))); }
```

Now `drop` is

```
function drop(arr) { return arr.shift(), arr; }
```

and `head` of course is

```
function head(arr) { return arr[0]; }
```

and `add` is

```
function add(arr, elt) { return arr.push(elt), arr; }
```

#### Another approach

I could also write a function to move `n` elements from position `i` to position `j`, using `splice`, as follows:

```
function move(arr, n, i, j) {
    arr.splice.apply(arr, [j-n+1, 0].concat(arr.splice(i, n)));
    return arr;
}
```

Then to `rotate` is to **move** one element **at the beginning** to the **end**:

```
function rotate(arr) { return move(arr, 1, 0, 999); }
```

Answer (score 3):

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and
>   returns the new length of the array.

`arr.push(arr[0])` doesn't return the array but a number which, obviously, has no `shift` function.

To my knowledge, there's no simple expression pushing an element to an array and returning that array. But in your case you may simply reverse the operations and do

```
arr.push(arr.shift());
```

Comment: @torazaburo No : concat returns a new array

Answer (score 1):

> I think it happens because I invoke the shift() method not on an array but on the pushed element.

Almost. [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the new length of the array. A number obviously doesn't have a `shift()` method.

Your method of putting it on two lines is the simplest way.

Comment: "the simplest" ? Look at my answer ;)